# python shell two-line command throws error when run remotely

Tags: python, bash

As part of a remote SSH command I want to run two python shell commands; to import and then run a command. I'm used to bash, am not familiar with python, and don't understand how to fix this error.

Here's my (stripped) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

updateTasks="\"from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTasks\nPeriodicTasks.update_changed()\""

ssh -n -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' -t -t ec2-user@<IP address> \
       "docker exec -ti \$(docker ps --format '{{.ID}}: {{.Names}}' | grep '${service}-'|\
        cut -d: -f1) /bin/bash -c '<several project-specific commands> ./manage.py shell <<< ${updateTasks}'"
```

Running this gets me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/<project specific>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/<project specific>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/<project specific>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/<project specific>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/<project specific>/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 101, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 1
    from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTasks\nPeriodicTasks.update_changed()
                                                                                    ^
```

(that ^ lines up with the `)` in the terminal, struggling to get it to match here)

To test it's not my commands that're wrong, if I run shell_plus instead and `updateTasks` is just `PeriodicTasks.update_changed()` it works. SSHing in manually and executing the two commands in succession also works. It's just something about my syntax that's failing. What do I have wrong?

Comment: use `;` instead of `\n`

Comment: @Poojan Oh man I feel like an idiot, that totally works! Not sure why that didn't show when googling. If you want the rep, feel free to answer

Comment: I don't think the escaped double quotes in the variable value can be correct, but with this many layers of shell and quoting to peel off, I can't say if that's all you need to fix here. Can you reduce this to a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To write one line python. Join all statement with `;`.
- Note that you can not use block statements like `if condition:` `for x in y:`. Statements like this will not work when combining with `;`.

  > use `;` instead of `\n`